# data disappears from the page after refreshing the page even though it is saved in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, controller, mongoose-schema

am working on social website project for learning purpose so the user can make posts and replying the posts and I made the replies in the same schema that I created for the post
But I thought of making replies deleteable and editable, so I created a special schema for replies

and now

I can add a reply to the post, but it disappears as soon as I refresh the page, even though it is stored in the database, and the username and profile picture do not appear in the reply.

old Post model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

 const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     postedBy: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User',
         required: true
     },
     text: {
         type: String,
         maxLength: 500
     },
     img: {
         type: String,
     },
     likes: [{
         // array of user id's
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User",
         default: []
     }],
     saves: [{
         // array of user id's
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User",
         default: []
     }],
     replies: [
         {
         userId: {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "User",
             required: true
         },
         text: {
             type: String,
             required: true
         },
         userProfilePic: {
             type: String
         },
         username: {
             type: String
         }
     }
     ]
 }, {timestamps: true}
 )

 const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

 export default Post;
```

new Post model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

 const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     postedBy: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'User',
         required: true
     },
     text: {
         type: String,
         maxLength: 500
     },
     img: {
         type: String,
     },
     video: {
         type: String,
         ref: "Upload"
     },
     likes: [{
         // array of user id's
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User",
         default: []
     }],
     saves: [{
         // array of user id's
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User",
         default: []
     }],
     replies: [{
                 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                 ref: 'Replies',
                 userId: {
                     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                     ref: "User",
                     required: true
                 },
         }]
 }, {timestamps: true}
 )

 const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

 export default Post;
```

Reply model after I created a special schema for it:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

 const ReplySchema = mongoose.Schema({
     text: {
         type: String,
         required: true
     },
     tag: Object,
     reply: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
     likes: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
     user: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
 }, {
     timestamps: true
 })

 const Reply = mongoose.model('Replies', ReplySchema);

 export default Reply;
```

controller function:

```
const replyCtrl = {
     createReply: async(req, res) => {
         try {
             const { postId, text, tag, comment } = req.body;

             const newReply = new Reply({
                 user: req.user._id, text, tag, comment
             })

             await Post.findOneAndUpdate({_id: postId}, {
                 $push: {replies: newReply._id}
             }, {new: true})

             await newReply.save();

             res.status(200).json(newReply)
         } catch (err) {
             console.log(err)
         }
     }
 }
```

if it's possible to make replies deleteable and editable with old Post Schema it will be better because it's more understandable for me

Comment: with old Post schema I was able to reply a post very correctly and the username and profile picture of user appear without any problems